# Undefined property: user::$load

Tags: forms, codeigniter, validation, activerecord

I got the following error:

> Undefined property: user::$load

Here is my code:

```
<?php defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

class users extends CI_Controller{


    function _construct(){
            parent::_construct();

        }  

    function index(){
        $this->load->view('login');
    }
    function Login(){
        $this->load->model('user');
        $query=$this->user->validate();
        if($query){
                $data=array(
                      'username'=>$this->input->post['UserName'],
                      'is_logged_in'=> true
                );
            $this->session->set_userdata($data);
            $this->load->view('purchaser_home');
        }
        else{
            $this->index();
        }
    }
}
?>
```

Why is the above error happening?

Comment: post complete error

Comment: @ABdulla  it says Undefined property: user::$load

Comment: no lines and all ??

Comment: @Abdulla 
A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Notice

Message: Undefined property: user::$load

Filename: libraries/Form_validation.php

Line Number: 147

Backtrace:

File: C:\xampp\htdocs\MMS\application\controllers\users.php
Line: 12
Function: model

File: C:\xampp\htdocs\MMS\index.php
Line: 292
Function: require_once

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change this to

```
'username'=>$this->input->post['UserName'],
```

this

```
'username'=>$this->input->post('UserName'),
```

---

and this should

```
$this->index();
```

change to

```
redirect('controllername')
```

---

In `autoload.php`

load Form hepler, URL helper as well

Comment: Thank you. I have changed my code but still I am getting the same error.

Comment: where is the `require_once`?? in your code there is nothing

Comment: I don't have require_once function

Comment: did you load `$this->load->library('form_validation');` ??

Comment: yes $autoload['libraries'] = array('database','form_validation','session');

Comment: load in controller too and check

Comment: thank you. I loaded it in my controller but it's not working.

Comment: @HizClick happy to help :)